# Show all the harmonic functions over $\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\{0\}$ such that $u(x)=f(|x|)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

This is an exercise of my course of PDE:

> Show all the harmonic functions over $\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\{0\}$ such that $u(x)=f(|x|)$.

**My Attempt**

A function $g$ is called harmonic if $\Delta g=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x_i^2}=0$. Let $r(x)=|x|$. We have that $u(x)=(f\circ r)(x)$. So
    $$
 \frac{\partial(f\circ r)(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(r(x))}{\partial r(x)}\frac{\partial r(x)}{\partial x}=\pm \frac{\partial f(r(x))}{\partial r(x)}
 $$
    and
    $$
 \frac{\partial f(r(x))}{\partial r(x)}=f'(x)
 $$
    So,
    $$
 \frac{\partial^2(f\circ r)}{\partial x^2}=\pm f''(x)\geq 0
 $$
    As $u(x)=f(|x|)=(f\circ r)(x)$, we give that $u(x)$ is harmonic if
    $$
 \frac{\partial^2 u(x)}{\partial x_i^2}=0, \forall i\in {1,...,N}
 $$

**I`m insecurity with this soluction.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here went wrong, firstly the $x_i$ derivative of $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}$ is $\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}}=\frac{x_i}{r}$.

And we seek **$f(r)=g(x)$**

And the $r$ derivative of $f$ is $f'(r)$ not $f'(x)$. 
Then we carefully calculate that the second $x_i$ derivative of $f$ to be $f''(r)\frac{x_i^2}{r^2}+f'(r)(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{x_i^2}{r^3})$

This should put you on better footing.

In conclusion sum what we have found to get:

$-\Delta g = -(f''(r)+\frac{n-1}{r}f'(r))=0$

Solve this linear second order ODE to obtain:

$f(r)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
b\ln(r)+c & \text{if } n=2\\
\frac{b}{r^{n-2}}+c & \text{if } n\ge 3 \end{array} \right\} $

Put this back in terms of $x$ and you have your solution.

Comment: Just say if you want me to put more in, I don't know all the bits you would be stuck with.

Comment: Thank you ellya. I'm writing right this (and embarrassing me about those mistakes!).

Comment: no worries, this is a place to learn, no one ever knows anything if they shy away and dont ask

Comment: In the fist derivative we get this:
$$
\frac{\partial(f\circ r)(x)}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r(x)}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial r}\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_N^2}}=\frac{f'(r) x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_N^2}}$$, right?

Comment: Now must I derive again?

Comment: Yeah take the second derivative with respect to $x_i$ as I have above, and then sum **all** of the second derivatives to find $\Delta f$, but remember we are looking for $g(r)=f(x)$ so what you have above is correct but should be written in terms of $g$.

Comment: I don't understand what is the $g$ function... What is it utility in this? $f'(r)\neq g'(x)$, right?

Comment: My mistake!!! I did not realise that you started your question with $g$, you are right! my bad!

Comment: I have put in an edit, to finalise

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for in the end?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really help with your chosen way to solve the problem, but it is a way to check the answer when you get it. It is geometric and intuitive, at least to me.

When I see words "harmonic function", I immediately think about taking integrals. Maybe it comes from physics, where electric potential $\varphi$ is harmonic (at places where there are no free charges), and people like to look at the flux of the electric field $\vec{E} = \nabla \varphi$ through closed surfaces.

So let's take some integrals. Since $u$ has spherical symmetry, let's take integrals over spheres.

Pick two numbers $0 < r_1 < r_2$ and look at two spheres $S_1 = \{x: |x| = r_1\}$ and $S_2 = \{x: |x| = r_2\}$. Between these two spheres is a spherical shell $D = \{x: r_1 \leq |x| \leq r_2 \}$. If we orient the spheres properly, then $\partial D = S_2 - S_1$. The minus sign means that the one sphere bounds the shell from the outside and the other from the inside.

Now let's go ahead and take the integral of $\Delta u$ over $D$. On the one hand it is zero, because $\Delta u = 0$. On the other hand it equals to the flux of the gradient $\nabla u$ by the [divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). So we have:
$$
0 = \int_D \Delta u \cdot dV = \oint_{S_2-S_1} \vec{\nabla u} \cdot \vec{dS},
$$
therefore
$$
\oint_{S_1} \vec{\nabla u} \cdot \vec{dS} = \oint_{S_2} \vec{\nabla u} \cdot \vec{dS}.
$$
Now we play the symmetry card. Synce $u(x) = f(|x|)$, the gradient of $u$ at point $x$ is parallel to vector $x$, and its value is simply $f'(|x|)$. More precisely, $\vec{\nabla u}(x) = \frac{x}{|x|} f'(|x|)$. If we look at $\vec{\nabla u}$ when $x$ lies on the sphere $S_1$, $\vec{\nabla u}$ is orthogonal to the surface of the sphere, and its magnitude is constant on all the sphere. So taking the integral becomes simple multiplication:
$$
\oint_{S_1} \vec{\nabla u} \cdot \vec{dS} = f'(r_1) \cdot \alpha \cdot r_1^{N-1}.
$$
Here $\alpha \cdot r_1^{N-1}$ is the surface area of $S_1$. The exact value of constant $\alpha$ is not important. It's enough to know that $\alpha$ doesn't depend on the radius, and $\alpha \neq 0$.

Now, doing the same for the integral over $S_2$, we arrive at the equality:
$$
f'(r_1) \cdot \alpha \cdot r_1^{N-1} = f'(r_2) \cdot \alpha \cdot r_2^{N-1}.
$$

But this holds for any $0 < r_1 < r_2$. This simply means that
$$
f'(r) \cdot r^{N-1} = \text{const}.
$$

So, whatever solution you find for $f$, it must satisfy this differential equation. In fact, you'll probably come to the exact same equation when you do it your way.

*NB:* as it is, this text only proves that $f'(r) \cdot r^{N-1} = \text{const}$ is a necessary condition. You can extend it to prove sufficiency, but it's probably better to get sufficiency using your way, and use my way for insurance.

Comment: You don't need that $r_2-r_1<\varepsilon, \forall \varepsilon>0$? I'm confuse with $\partial D=S_1-S_2$. Thank you for all the details!!!

Comment: @Felipe no, I don't need it here. I never used it. That's the beauty of it: there was nothing infinitesimal in the process. If I wanted to prove it the other way, that my differential equation *implies* that $\Delta u = 0$, then yes, I would probably need to look at two spheres close to each other and say that $\int_D \Delta u \cdot dV$ equals $\operatorname{Vol}(D)$ times $\Delta u$ at some point inside of $D$, plus some small correction that decreases faster than $\operatorname{Vol}(D)$ as $r_2 - r_1 \to 0$.

Comment: But if $D=\{x: r_1\leq |x|\leq r_2 \}$ so, $\partial D=\{x: x=r_1$ or $x=r_2\}\neq S_1\setminus S_2$?

Comment: $\partial D = S_2 - S_1$ is just parlance. Strictly speaking, $\partial D = S_2 \cup S_1$. But we are taking fluxes here, and they depend on the choice of orientation. So that "$-$" between $S_2$ and $S_1$ is a reminder that for the divergence theorem to work, you need to orient $S_1$ and $S_2$ in the opposite ways.

Comment: $\partial D\neq S_2\cup S_1$, right? Remember that $S_2=\{x:|x|<r_2\}$

Comment: That was a misprint. $S_2$ is a sphere, not a ball. I fixed it.

Comment: His answer was really motivating for me to study partial differential equations. The physical motivation seems really important. 'm Rewriting your answer step by step to understand it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I think it would be most useful if you work through both ways. My way is leisurely and relaxed, but it is important to be able to do things with "brute force" (which in this case is the way with partial derivatives).

Comment: Also, the only known (to me) relavance to physics is for $N = 3$. Then indeed you should get $u$ that looks exactly the same as the [electric potential of a point charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential#Electric_potential_due_to_a_point_charge).

Comment: A little question: $\vec{\nabla} u = \langle \vec{u}, \vec{n} \rangle$?

Comment: This seems quite overcomplicated

Comment: @Felipe $\vec{\nabla u}$ is the [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of $u$.

Comment: @ellya That is subjective. To me that is the easiest solution that I was able to do entirely in my head before posting here. But I agree that many will find the direct way easier, hence the disclaimer in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Actually, I just read it again, now I'm not so tired and its pretty good, nice to see another approach.